# Can't join 2 tables

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

In our query we have 2 tables that we want to join. But we get the following error:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry
 for table "component"   Position: 48   at
 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
    at
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:406)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:286)   at datab.Datab.testDB(Datab.java:73)    at datab.Datab.main(Datab.java:60)
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void testDB(Connection con){
  //RUN AN EXAMPLE QUERY
  try {
    if (!con.isClosed())
    {
      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      String query = "SELECT * FROM \"Component\" inner join \"Kind\" on Component.Kind_ID = Kind.ID";
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);                

      while (rs.next())
      {                 
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " "  + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3));                            
      }
    }                    
  } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: another good example why quoted identifiers are not a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

This is your SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Component" 
   inner join "Kind" on Component.Kind_ID = Kind.ID
```

The table name `"Component"` is a different table name than `component`. Once you start using those dreaded quoted identifiers, you have to use them **everywhere**. You didn't show us your table definitions, but I suspect you also need to quote the column names:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Component" 
   inner join "Kind" on "Component"."Kind_ID" = "Kind"."ID"
```

If you can change this, I strongly recommend to re-create the tables **without** using double quotes.

More details about quoted identifiers are in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Shouldn't one of those `"Component"` be without double quotes?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: not according to the error message.

Comment: Hi Mark, Netbeans wants us to qoute table names like this \"tablename\"

Comment: Then one of those should be `"component"`, right? As `"Component"` will be case sensitive, and `Component` will be case insensitive and handled as `"component"`. As it stands the sentence _"The table name `"Component"` is a different table name than `"Component"`"_ doesn't make much sense, as they are exactly the same.

Comment: Just to add that the problem is not how we join those tables in normal conditions. Problem is how we do it in Netbeans. Apparently Netbeans have some special syntax for that.

Comment: I understand, but the sentence I quoted doesn't make sense as you have currently phrased it.

Comment: @ssjmessi10: the problem has **nothing** to do with NetBeans. It's all about syntax rules regarding those dreaded quoted identifiers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Ah, now I see it ;) Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @ssjmessi10: just run those two statements from my answer in a SQL client and you will understand